# Laravel Validator / Uploaded File Fails At Required

Tags: validation, file-upload, laravel

**"dd"** output of **Input::all()** in postController:

```
array(8) {
["_token"]=>
string(40) "6WZ87M1LCiVCsaUS9HbjZckRibXfF2RP69LCpW7K",
...
...
["svg"]=>
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#9 (7) {
  ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  string(39) "Screenshot from 2013-06-18 17:07:27.png"
  ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  string(9) "image/png"
  ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  int(29747)
  ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
  int(0)
  ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(14) "/tmp/phpdRTDU7"
  ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(9) "phpdRTDU7"
}
}
```

Validation:

```
$rules = array('svg' => 'required');

$check = Validator::make(Input::except('_token'), $rules);

if($check->fails()){
return Redirect::back()->withErrors($check);    
}else{
return Redirect::back()->with('message', 'No problem'); 
}
```

And I get the error message:

Error message:
The svg field is required.

Even if I upload file as you see on dd output, it shows that error always.

Thanks,

Comment: did you add files option in form open?

Comment: Yes, enctype=multipart/form-data.

Comment: Oh, the problem was using Input::except() instead of all(). I think it doesn't contain files, just inputs. Solved. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

user2413500 found that the problem was using `Input::except('_token')` which did not include the file object. However, `Input::all()` does include the file object. This seems to be a bug which I'll report, but the definition of Input::except is "all" minus the items you don't want.

But what seems to be happening is "all" minus the items you don't want, minus your file!

Itrulia and Taylor say [this is not a bug](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues/2150).

However, these are **confusingly** not identical statements when you have a $_FILE posted...

```
$params = Input::except('_token'); // Missing file inputs!
$params = array_except(Input::all(), '_token'); // The current solution.
```

Be on guard! :)